# Read file into char*

Tags: c, file

Because I use the task so often, I wrote a C header for reading a file. I never formally learned C, so I'd really appreciate a code review on the code.

As a matter of personal taste, I do not put a space between the final parenthesis and an opening brace (`){`).

**readfile.h**

```
#ifndef _READ_FILE_INCL
#define _READ_FILE_INCL
#include <stdio.h>     /* for FILE, fopen, getc, fclose, EOF */
#include <stdlib.h>    /* for malloc, realloc */

// the amount of bytes the file is initially guessed to be
#ifndef _READFILE_GUESS
    #define _READFILE_GUESS 256
#endif

/*
 * function `read_file`
 * arguments: a file name (char*)
 * returns: the contents of the file (char*) or NULL if:
 *   1. the file does not exist
 *   2. memory allocation failed
 * return value must be freed
 */
char* read_file(char* name){
    FILE* file;
    file = fopen(name, "r");

    // 1. the file does not exist: return null
    if(!file)
        return NULL;

    // allocate memory according to the initial guess
    // (+ 1) for trailing null byte
    char* result = malloc(sizeof(char) * _READFILE_GUESS + 1);


    // 2. memory allocation failed
    if(result == NULL)
        return NULL;

    // the position in the string to write the character to
    size_t pos = 0;

    // the amount of memory allocated for the string
    size_t capacity = _READFILE_GUESS;

    // character to hold the currently-read character from the file
    char ch;

    // until the character is the EOF character
    while((ch = getc(file)) != EOF){
        // update the character at position `pos` to `ch`
        result[pos++] = ch;

        // if the next position would exceed bounds
        if(pos >= capacity){
            // add the guess to the capacity
            capacity += _READFILE_GUESS;

            // allocate memory accordingly
            // (+ 1) for trailing null byte
            result = realloc(result, sizeof(char) * capacity + 1);

            // 2. memory allocation failed
            if(result == NULL)
                return NULL;
        }
    }

    // close the file
    fclose(file);

    // remove extra memory
    result = realloc(result, sizeof(char) * pos);

    // 2. memory allocation failed
    if(result == NULL)
        return NULL;

    // `pos` now points to the index after the last character read
    result[pos] = '\0';

    return result;
}

#undef _READFILE_GUESS

/*
 * MIT License
 * 
 * Copyright (c) 2017 Conor O'Brien
 * 
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
 * of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
 * in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
 * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 * 
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
 * copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 * 
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
 * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
 * SOFTWARE.
 */

#endif
```

Comment: Just curious, the code is valid, but it more common to put an extern declaration of the function in a header file and then have a C file that contains the actual function?

Comment: @pacmaninbw As I said, I never have formally learned C. FWIW I don't know what an "extern deceleration" is

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Getting Size of File

You can get the size of file (without asking the filesystem) by using `fseek()` and `ftell()`.

```
if (fseeko(file, 0, SEEK_END) != 0) {
    // Error State do something
}
off_t sizeOfFile = ftello(file);
if (fseeko(file, 0, SEEK_SET) != 0) {
    // Error State do something
}

// Your file is now ready to be read and the size of the file is
// in `sizeOfFile`
```

### Identifier Names

The identifier `_READFILE_GUESS` is reserved for the implementation. Don't use `_` (underscore) as the first character in an identifier name.

### Realloc

This is the wrong way to use `realloc`:

```
result = realloc(result, sizeof(char) * capacity + 1);
```

As you have noticed, when `realloc` fails it returns `NULL`. But it does not free the `result` value in this case. This means you have overwritten the value of `result` with null and thus leaked the memory it was pointing at.

```
char* newArea = realloc(result, sizeof(char) * capacity + 1);
if (newArea == NULL) {
    // Error condition handle it
    // You should probably release `result` by calling `free()`
    // before returning result
}
result = newArea;
```

### Reading

Why are you only reading one byte at a time?

```
while((ch = getc(file)) != EOF)
```

Why not (attempt to) read `capacity` bytes at a time?

```
size_t blocksRead= 0;
size_t totalRead = 0;

while(1) {
    size_t read = fread(result + (blocksRead * capacity) + totalRead, 1, capacity - totalRead, file);
    if (ferror(file) != 0) {
        // Error State Deal with it.
    }
    totalRead += read;
    if (feof(file)) {
        break;
    }
    if (totalRead == capacity) {
        ++blocksRead;
        totalRead = 0;
        // Handle resize of block if you need too.
    }
}
```

### License

Also note that by pasting the code into any Stack Exchange site you are already dual licensing your code under the [CC license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) (see the bottom of the page for details).

So though your MIT License is valid it is not the only license this code is now available under.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that only double underscores (`__`) were reserved for implementation usage.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Yes those are reserved in any scope. Also 1) A leading underscore followed by any letter in a file scope. 2) A leading underscore followed by an uppercase letter in any scope. From the C standard `7.1.3 Reserved identifiers`.

Comment: This question/answer is about C++, but it quotes part of the C standard (as it applies to C++ as well). http://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/14065

Comment: So would making the variable name lowercase avoid such reservation issues?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Sure. But then you are breaking the tradition of making macros all upper case (which is also important). Better to follow the standard convention of not using the underscore at the beginning of an identifier.

Comment: Should I favor `size_t` over `long` for the file size? Or is `size_t` not large enough for some files?

Comment: `read()` returns `size_t`. So you should use `size_t` as this will be large enough but `long` may not be on all systems.

Comment: "Without asking the filesystem"?  That's exactly what you're doing with `fseek()`.  I think you meant "without guessing".

Comment: But you use `long sizeOfFile = ftell(file);` ?

Comment: @TobySpeight: By asking the file system I meant using calls that interact directly with the filesystem and know the size of the file: like `fstat()` or file system specific calls. The `fseek` and `ftell` are more abstract and are dealing with streams.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ and that is why we have code review. Fixed.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ and that is why we have code review. Updated to `ftello()` and `fseeko()` so we can cope with modern file systems.

Comment: In which case, you should mention that `ftello()` and `fseeko()` aren't Standard C, but are in POSIX.

Comment: "The fseek and ftell are more abstract and are dealing with streams" - I guess the key point you're making is that they use the `FILE*` abstraction, so consistent with the rest of the code, and requiring nothing outside of Standard C?  That might be something you could specifically point out.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just getting back to this. I tried making the changes concerning getting the file size from the system, and it seems that `SEEK_BEG` is not in `stdio.h`. Where might it be? (`error: 'SEEK_BEG' undeclared (first use in this function)`)

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Oops. I mean `SEEK_SET`. Fixed above.

Comment: So, if I were to use the `fseeko`/`ftello` method, would I be better off using `fread`?

Comment: Isn't it `fseeko(file, 0, SEEK_END)` instead of `fseeko(file, SEEK_END, 0)`?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Yes. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseeko.3.html

Answer (score 2):

Do not put functions in header files.

Headers are the public interface to your module, so they should contain the declarations of the public functions and (possible) variables. The C source file is the private part of the module that actually contains the implementation.

So, `readfile.h`

```
#ifndef _READ_FILE_INCL
#define _READ_FILE_INCL

/*
 * function `read_file`
 * arguments: a file name (char*) ...
 */
extern char* read_file(char* name);
#endif
```

Then the implementation, `readfile.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>     /* for FILE, fopen, getc, fclose, EOF */
#include <stdlib.h>    /* for malloc, realloc */
#include "readfile.h"

/* this isn't required outside this module, so we can define it here */
#define READFILE_GUESS 256

char* read_file(char* name){
    /* implementation */
}
```

Then, with your main program in `myprog.c`, compile them all together with something like this:

```
gcc -Wall $FLAGS -o myprog myprog.c readfile.c
```

---

As for the code itself, I won't repeat what @Loki stated.

But, you're not handling errors fully, a memory allocation error will leave the file opened:

```
file = fopen(name, "r");
if(!file)
    return NULL;

char* result = malloc(sizeof(char) * _READFILE_GUESS + 1);
if(result == NULL)
    return NULL;          /* Here, the function returns with 'file' open */
```

(Granted, that is not likely to matter much, since if `malloc` fails your program might not be able to continue anyway. But still.)

Make sure to `fclose(file)` on every error exit after opening the file, either in every single place where you do an early `return`, or by collecting the cleanup code and `return` to a single place.

Comment: What about headers like `stdlib.h`? Those define functions, don't they?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ, [declare, not define](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration) The `stdlib.h` on my system has a bunch of typedefs, #defines, and function declarations like `extern double atof (const char *__nptr);` (with some macros sprinkled in, most likely related to compiler-specific notes)

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Its a rule of thumb. By placing function definitions in the header file you are making the file messier and harder to read (the standard library is well documented so we don't care if it is messy). Personally I function longer than a single line I place in the source file (unless I have a very good reason not to).